# Need help creating a special function

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I'm creating a special function in a game and needed some help with the maths end of it.

Essentially, I need a programmable, non-linear function so that $f(100) = 0$, and $f(0) = 100$ (or some other number, I'd have to play around with this). Every value in between approaches $f(0)$ as they get smaller (i.e $f(30)$ could be something $\sim85$).

It needs to be non-linear and increase with each decreasing value of $x$.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There are a lot of reasonable function. You should elaborate more on the details. For example, what the function is for. Why nonlinear (what if someone give you an almost linear function?)? Any other desirable quality: easy of calculation, derivative, convexity, etc.? Otherwise there are plenty of possible answer to this question. For example, $100(1-(x/100)^{1.2})$

Comment: @Gina Almost linear may work. I need it for an oddly shaped health bar in a video game. A linear function may work, actually. A linear function that has a maximum of 100 at $f(0)$ and a minimum of 0 at $f(100)$. How would I go about creating such a function? Sorry I'm not fantastic with this sort of math, I'm just a UI programmer >.<

Comment: If the question is about how to program the function, it's probably not a place. If it's about the mathematical description of the function, well there are too many of them. One way is to use the function $f(x)=100(1-(\frac{x}{100})^{\alpha})$ where $\alpha>0$ is a parameter you can pick with will influence the curvature of the function. But there are plenty more, if you need the function to satisfy some other requirements. (the function above come from the observation that $x^{\alpha}$ is a function from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ and the rest is just rescaling it to $100$)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you mentioned that a linear function will also work. This is the simplest kind of function you can use. There is only one linear function satisfying your requirements, and that is:
 $f(x)=100-x$